# Unity GVR - Missing Virtual Reality SDKs from list

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

After importing GoogleVRForUnity I can't find the VR SDKs Cardboard and Daydream in Player Settings -> Other -> Virtual Reality SDKs.

[image: Unity Player Settings]

Comment: Which version of Unity do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cardboard SDK and DayDream are available on the beta only for the moment

Answer (score 0):

You do not see the cardboard and daydream under virtual reality SDK since you have not changed the platform. These two Sdks are only supposed to work with the Android platform. By default, when you create a project in Unity it selects windows project as default. Please change the platform settings from build options menu and you will be able to see the those.